# Iterating li items in gwt while using ui binder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am having an unordered list in my ui.xml. Is there a way I can **iterate through the list** **items**

(only the list items)
 in my owner class so that I could remove style from certain li items on occurrence of some event. just like $.each() in jquery.

how the ul is laid in my ui.xml>>

```
            <ul class="{style.breadCrumb}" ui:field="bCrumbHeader">
                <li>Counterparty Type</li>
                <li>Quantitative Criteria</li>
                <li>Qualitative Criteria</li>
                <li>View Ratings</li>
            </ul>

        </g:HTMLPanel>
```

My owner class need a logic to be put inside iterateThroughList()

```
    @UiField
    UListElement bCrumbHeader;

private void iterateThroughList{
//some logic so that I can access each li item inside a loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumble upon the same scenario use **getElementsByTagName("li")**

The above said method will return a nodelist of li elements.
Acess the required element from the list and use **addClassName** to add the specified style.

```
 @UiField
 UListElement bCrumbHeader;

    private void iterateThroughList{

     //bCrumbHeader is the uifield associated with ul
     NodeList<Element> eList= bCrumbHeader.getElementsByTagName("li");

     for(int i = 0; i < eLsit.getLength(); i++) { 

             Element aNode = eLsit.getItem(i); 
             aNode.addClassName(style.active());
        }
    }
```